# Rails 'State_machine' - How to access combination of states from two state machines are present for a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I have two state machines

```
 1)basic_details with states 
  i)no
  ii)in_progress 
  iii)completed
```

and 
    2)enrollments with states
     i)no
     ii)in_progress 
     iii)completed

Now to get records where basic_details is 'no' I can use

```
object.with_basic_details('no')
```

Likewise I need to get records where

```
 basic_details('completed') and enrolments('no')
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: are they both scopes? if so, can you just chain them: `object.with_basic_details('no').with_enrolments('no')`

Comment: That does the magic!

Comment: ok, I'll move it to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scopes can be chained and both will take effect eg if you want objects that are in the scope of "no" for basic_details and "in_progress" for enrolments, use:

```
object.with_basic_details('no').with_enrolments('in_progress')
```